# No operations defined in spec! appear after setting context-path in jhipster application

Tags: jhipster, swagger-ui

I made a monolith java application (java + angular) from jhipster-generator `v7.9.3` and then specified its servers on `http://localhost:8080/demo/` by the below configuration

1. Set context-path: `/demo` from `application.yml`
2. Set `<base href="/demo/" />` from `index.html`
3. Go to `Administration` > `API` > It showed an empty API description with the message `No operations defined in spec!`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Someone entered an issue about this in the JHipster project. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/22542 I'm not sure how to fix it. If you deploy your app to the `/` context (by naming it ROOT.war), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I deploy `demo` app with subdomain `demo`:

1. Modify: `./src/main/webapp/index.html` --> Change `<base href="/" />` line to `<base href="/demo/" />`
2. In a terminal, build the executable: `./gradlew -Pprod clean bootJar`
3. Copy/paste executable jar from `./build/libs/demo.jar` to the server
4. On the server, execute: `java -jar demo.jar --server.servlet.context-path=/demo`
5. Open a browser, and navigate to: http://localhost:8080/demo/

**NB**: I *don't* modify application.yml, and I **DO** include `--server.servlet.context-path=/demo` in the command line.

Comment: 2. In a terminal, build the executable: `./gradlew -Pprod clean bootJar` does not provide API doc in swagger